# Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed:

Tags: ios, flutter

Having trouble creating IOS app using flutter.
can any one help how i can solve this issue??

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            7.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception: Failed to codesign /Users/vijaidwivedi/Projects/users/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework/App with identity -.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.

Tried
deleting the build directory
cleaning the flutter app
updating the app pubs

but no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Open Runner in Xcode then Go to Targets > Built Phases > Run Script:
Add the following

```
xattr -cr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData || echo Clear
```

Then build the project.

Answer (score 1):

have the same error as you

this error came after i install flutter_launcher_icons and gen the icon .png with alpha removal from the image

in this newer lib version you can leave the alpha flag and use setting in pubspec

```html
flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  image_path: " " 
  remove_alpha_ios: true
```

and regen everything and it's solve my problem

Comment: I know this probably won't be the solution for many, but it was for me. In case anyone is using `flutter_launcher_icons` (the new version of `flutter_icons`), try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, the error message is not very clear. I've solved that by deleting assets with the same names but different extensions. For me, it was empty_cart.jpeg and empty_cart.png.

Answer (score 0):

It was an image name that prevented me from compiling my project.

After elimination it was only an image with the option on Mac to "hide the extension" (⌘+i on the file in Finder)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the command

```
xattr -cr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData || echo Clear
```

to a "Run Script" build phase in Xcode by following these steps:

1. Open your Flutter project in a terminal or command prompt.
2. Run the following command to open your iOS project in Xcode:

> `open ios/Runner.xcworkspace`

This command will open Xcode with your Flutter iOS project.

3. In Xcode, locate and select the "Runner" target in the Project Navigator on the left side of the window. It's usually listed under the "Workspace" or "Project" section.
4. In the main Xcode window, select the "Runner" target.
5. Click on the "Build Phases" tab at the top of the Xcode window.
6. In the "Build Phases" section, you will see a list of build phases.
   To add a new "Run Script" build phase, click the "+" button at the
   top left of the "Build Phases" section and select "New Run Script
   Phase."
7. A new "Run Script" build phase will be added to your project. You
   can drag and drop it to the appropriate location in the build
   process if needed.
8. Click on the disclosure triangle next to the "Run Script" phase to
   expand it.
9. In the "Run Script" section, you can paste the following command
   into the script box:

> `xattr -cr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData || echo Clear`

Make sure that the "Shell" field is set to

> /bin/sh.

10. Save your Xcode project.

Finally, build your project by clicking the "Build" button in Xcode or the play button

Answer (score 0):

write this command on terminal `flutter clean`if you add dependency you must add it again  and run project

Comment: I edit my massage bro let's do it  it fully working

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. To solve this issue make sure that you don't have more than one /assets endpoints and in assets you don't have any image with same name and different format.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. While googling, i came to this post. Looking upvotes, i tried the solution provided by @Mathew. Still same error msg came. Again, i started viewing other comments. @fingerup's comment remind me of something. I had added a screenshot image file only named as "connect" within assets directory which was saved automatically as png file. Then i renamed the file as "connect-vendor.png" explicitly. Later the error was gone and build was successful.

Then i tried removing script that i added following @Mathew and rebuild the project. Still build was successful. So, in my case, the cause of issue was naming of png image file within assets directory.